# Google not ask to accept permissions on apps script, Error Attempted to execute, but could not save

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, youtube-api

[Error Attempted to execute YoutubeScraper, but could not save.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETITF.png)

```
function YoutubeScraper() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet()

  var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet,id" {q: "coding", maxResults:50})

  Logger.log(search)
}
```

I couldn't save too

> Error Attempted to execute YoutubeScraper, but could not save.

Comment: I think that in your script, `,` is required to be added. So, please modify `var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet,id" {q: "coding", maxResults:50})` to `var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet,id", { q: "coding", maxResults: 50 })` and test it again.

Comment: Check the red  underline in your screenshot.